# Terminal SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, mongodb, syntax, terminal

Trying to connect to a Mongo DB database through this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testaroo');

mongoose.connection.once('open'.function(){
console.log('Connection has been made');                                           

}).on('error', function(error){
console.log('Connection Error:', error);
});
```

But, when I try to connect to it through Terminal

```
MG-MC-iMacs-iMac:~ MG-MC-TJUBA$ node mongodb/PingPongDB/connection.js
```

It gives me this error:

```
/Users/MG-MC-TJUBA/mongodb/PingPongDB/connection.js:6
mongoose.connection.once('open'.function(){
                                     ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

From what I'm seeing it says I'm missing a ')' that is already there and needed.

Comment: Use a tool like jsHint or jsLInt or one of the other linters out there...

Comment: replace dot (.) with comma (,) after open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error in your code

```
mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
console.log('Connection has been made');                                           

}).on('error', function(error){
console.log('Connection Error:', error);
});
```